# Is the Swift Array sorted method thread safe for a local copy of an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, thread-safety

My app is experiencing a crash during the sort on line 2 below.  This happens inside a method on a `ViewController` when a `NSNotification` comes in to trigger the sort and refresh the display.

My understanding is that the `devices` array on line 1 is a new array created from the dictionary, so accessing the elements is tread safe, even though the dictionary might change.

Even if the `serialID` (a `String?`) changes during the sort, I would not think this could cause a crash.

What am I missing?  What could possibly cause a bad access inside the sort?

```
1: var devices = deviceDict.valuesArray() // See Edit below
2: let sortedDevices = devices.sorted(by: { ($0.serialID ?? "") < ($1.serialID ?? "") })
```

I have no known way to reproduce this. I have only seen it in crash reports like below.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000f9a70f7c0
VM Region Info: 0xf9a70f7c0 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 55741315009  Bytes before following region: 630130752
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO              280000000-2a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
--->  GAP OF 0xd20000000 BYTES
      commpage (reserved)      fc0000000-1000000000 [  1.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [4510]
Triggered by Thread:  9

...
  
  Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a6ae2dd0 objc_release + 16 (objc-runtime-new.h:1589)
1   OAPP                            0x00000001044c35e4 specialized UnsafeMutableBufferPointer._stableSortImpl(by:) + 364 (DeviceViewController.swift:0)
2   OAPP                            0x00000001044c17f0 specialized MutableCollection<>.sort(by:) + 100
2   OAPP                            0x00000001044baf60 DeviceViewController.generateDeviceList() + 1644
4   OAPP                            0x00000001044b67ac DeviceViewController.refreshDeviceTableView() + 524 (DeviceViewController.swift:655)
5   OAPP                            0x00000001044bb7a4 DeviceViewController.handleSyncStateNotification(_:) + 680 (DeviceViewController.swift:821)
...
```

**EDIT**:  The `deviceDict` is actually on a custom class that wraps a dictionary some thread safe accessors, and I convert the dictionary values to an array in that class.  (In my original post, I tried to simplify the code so as not to distract from the issue of the crash being on an operation of an Array, but I seem to have confused things by doing that simplification. Sorry!)

```
public class SafeDict<Element> {
    fileprivate let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.myapp.SafeDict", attributes: .concurrent)
    fileprivate var dictionary:[String:Element] = [:] 
...
    public func valuesSafe() -> Dictionary<String, Element>.Values {
        var returnValues: Dictionary<String, Element>.Values = Dictionary<String, Element>().values
        queue.sync {
            returnValues = self.dictionary.values
        }
        return returnValues
    }
    
    public func valuesArray() -> [Element] {
        var values: [Element] = []
        queue.sync {
            for element in self.valuesSafe() {
                values.append(element)
            }
        }
        return values
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be that the local copy is optimised away. Notice how the stack trace shows `MutableCollection<>.sort(by:)`, rather than the non-mutating `sorted` that you wrote.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Any thoughts on how I might prevent this optimization?

Comment: Try manually copying the array, perhaps? `var devices = Array(deviceDict.values())` But since you have no way to reproduce this, I guess you can't test that this works/doesn't work either?

Comment: `deviceDict.values()` doesn't copy the contents, instead it returns a "view" of the dictionary storage. And if that dictionary is a mutable one, that gets changes by another thread during the sorting, then, well, boom :).

Comment: @davidgyoung where is your `values()` method declared? Dictionary has only a `values` property not a method.

Comment: See my edit that clarifies a simplification in the original post.

Comment: The new edit changes things, theoretically with he updated code, there should not be any data race, excepting if the dictionary elements are objects that get updated from multiple threads.

Comment: BTW, what kind of values is `deviceDict` holding?

Comment: It is a Swift class (not a struct) with mostly String members.  It represents an external Bluetooth device that is detected and updated from a few different threads (used for Bluetooth scanning, Bluetooth connections, API calls and the UI.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`devices` is not an Array. It's a `Dictionary.Values`. It's a lazy view into deviceDict.

But none of that matters. Mutable access to deviceDict on multiple threads is always undefined behavior. If it's possible for `serialID` to change on another thread without some kind of synchronization, you've already made an error. The `deviceDict.values()` line would be invalid; having nothing to do with later accesses to it.

But of course the `sorted` line is more likely to be where that undefined behavior bites you, since it's going to walk a lot of values, which might be moved in memory if `deviceDict` has to resize or otherwise modify its backing storage.

Comment: Putting the dictionary aside for a moment, I would think the same thing would apply to arrays.  In terms of the changing array elements like `serialID` from thread B while thread A is sorting the array, would this really cause a crash vs. just sorting incorrectly?  If so, it would seem impossible to ever do a thread safe sort on  a copy of an array in Swift unless you do a deep copy.  Do you think this is true?

Comment: Copy-on-write is thread-safe. So it is safe to work on a copy, even though it may share a backing store. This assumes the contents are also value types. If they're classes, then yes, modifying them in the middle of a sort is dangerous, and could crash or mis-sort. Violating the preconditions of a sort (including that values aren't changing behind its back) can generate fatal errors, not just bad sorts.

Comment: The most important thing to keep in mind with Swift thread-safety is that Arrays are not just fixed, contiguous chunks of memory like in C. Modifying them, even in ways that don't change their length, can move them to other areas of memory. So even reading at one index while writing at another index is UB.

Comment: I edited my question to remove a simplification.  The edit should make clear that devices is an array even though the original post suggested otherwise (sorry for confusing things I was trying the opposite!)  Regardless, I think you are saying that the crash could be caused by changing the `serialID: String?` property of the object inside the array on another thread.  Yes?

Comment: After using a serial DispatchQueue around every read/write access to any field on these objects shared across threads the crashes did go away.  I am very surprised by this because it means that any Swift code that uses mutable fields across threads is subject to these crashes, even apps that do not explicitly create their own threads but use non-UI thread callbacks from built-in iOS APIs.

Comment: That is completely correct. You must be aware of what queue you are on when you are called back and manage accesses accordingly. This has always been true (in ObjC as well as Swift).

Comment: It is more pronounced in Swift because of how structs work (modifying any field of a struct modifies the entire struct), but it's always been something Cocoa developers must deal with. And as you say, it is a major source of crashes when they don't. (This is exactly why Swift's new structured concurrency is based on the Actor model, which makes this requirement a formal part of the language and allows the compiler enforce it.)

Comment: BTW, if you want to keep a concurrent queue for faster reading, look at `.async(flags: .barrier)`. With this you can give writes exclusive access, while reads are still in parallel. That said, general-purpose thread-safe collections are usually a bad design choice. You usually want to manage concurrency at a higher layer than the collection. Context switching for every read is expensive and error-prone.

Comment: ObjC had "atomic properties" and `@synchronized` which turned out to be much less useful than they sound (and were not brought to Swift). https://web.archive.org/web/20201111225329/http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/13/objectivce-c-atomic-properties-threading-andor-custom-settergetter/